# Woocommerce -- Get Attribute Value For Products in Cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, product

I am using Woocommerce to set up an ecommerce page that sells meal plans.

Currently, I have a [product customizer](https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-products-wizard/16254396) that allows the customer to create their own meal plan / composite.

I am trying to pass some values on to the plugin's widget. Specifically, I am attempting to retrieve the names and values of product attributes that are currently in my cart.

The product attributes display nutrition information for each composite product. When a customer adds a product to their cart, I would like the nutrition info (product attributes) to populate.

For the first piece, I was able to retrieve product attribute names for in-cart items by using the below code (from [here](https://www.webetutorial.com/question/show-woocommerce-product-attributes-on-cart-page/)):

```
 $item_data = $cart_item['data'];
 // print_r($item_data);
  $attributes = $item_data->get_attributes();
  //print_r($attributes);
foreach ( $attributes as $attribute => $attribute_term ) {
$term = get_term_by('slug', $attribute_name, $attribute);    
echo wc_attribute_label( $attribute ).': '.$term->term;
}
```

This only displays the name of the attribute. Exactly what I need for column 1.

However, I want to display the attribute value in column 2, but I'm unsure how to manipulate the above code to achieve this. Currently, I have the same code passed into column 2

[Example of current situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpuKq.png)

So step 1 (above), would be to print the product attribute values that correspond to the product attribute name in column 1.

Step 2 would be to take this a little further by summing up attributes that are common between products. For instance, if product 1 and product 2 both have the "fats" attribute with values of "2" and "3" accordingly, then I hope to print out "5" (the sum for the common product attributes).

Any insight is greatly appreciated. I have limited programming knowledge, and am learning as I go with this project.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example code that might help you

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'customizing_cart_item_data', 10, 3);
function customizing_cart_item_data( $item_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    $term_names = array();

    // Get product categories
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $cart_item['product_id'], 'product_cat' );

    if( count($terms) > 0 ){
        foreach( $terms as $term ) $term_names[] = $term->name;

        $item_name .= '<p class="item-category" style="margin:12px 0 0; font-size: .875em;">
            <strong class="label">' . _n( 'Category', 'Categories', count($terms), 'woocommerce' ) . ': </strong>
            <span class="values">' . implode( ', ', $term_names ) . '</span>
        </p>';
    }
    return $item_name;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Debasis, I appreciate you sharing this, however, it's not achieving what I had hoped.

The code in the OP allows me to list all the product attribute "names" of the products in my cart.

How can I modify the code I shared to instead display the product attribute "values" of the products in my cart?

Thank you :)